# Xamarin Forms Binding with namespace declaration error

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin and I'm trying to bind my ViewModel to the View but I couldn't do it yet.

Here's the code.

(Model)

```
namespace CadastroProdutos
{
    public class Produto
    {
        public string Codigo { get; set; }
        public string Identificacao { get; set; }
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

(Observable Model)

```
namespace CadastroProdutos
{
    public class ObservableProduto : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Produto produto;
        public ObservableProduto()
        {
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Codigo
        {               
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(produto.Codigo, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    produto.Codigo = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Codigo");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return produto.Codigo;
            }
        }

        public string Identificacao
        {
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(produto.Identificacao, StringComparison.Ordinal)) 
                {
                    produto.Identificacao = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Identificacao");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return produto.Identificacao;
            }
        }

        public string Tipo
        {
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(produto.Tipo, StringComparison.Ordinal)) 
                {
                    produto.Tipo = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Tipo");
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return produto.Tipo;
            }
        }

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler == null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(ViewModel)

```
namespace CadastroProdutos
{
    public class ListProdutoViewModel
    {
        ObservableCollection<ObservableProduto> produtos;

        public ListProdutoViewModel()
        {
            produtos = new ObservableCollection<ObservableProduto>();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ObservableProduto> Produtos
        {
            set
            {
                if (value != produtos)
                {
                    produtos = value;
                }
            }
            get
            {
                return produtos;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(View)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CadastroProdutos;assembly=CadastroProdutos"
    x:Class="CadastroProdutos.ListProduto"
    Title="Listagem de Produtos">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ListView x:Name="listView" Margin="20,40,20,20" ItemsSource="{Binding Produtos}">
            <ListView.BindingContext>
                <local:ListProdutoViewModel />
            </ListView.BindingContext>
            <ListView.Header>
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" >
                        <Label Text="Produtos" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ListView.Header>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Identificacao}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Getting an error "Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException Position 10:6. Type local:ListProdutoViewModel not found in xmlns clr-namespace:CadastroProdutos;assembly=CadastroProdutos". 
What am I missing on the namespace declaration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two things. 1) Is XamlCompilation turned on? 2) Have you deleted your bin/obj folders?

Comment: If you look at how this `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CadastroProdutos;assembly=CadastroProdutos"` is assembled you will see that the first value is the namespace, that seems to checkout, and the second value is the assembly. Are you sure the assembly name is correct? So you have a DLL called CadastroProdutos? If both values are correct, indeed try to rebuild and clean your whole solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that whether ListProdutoViewModel is deifined under the namespace - CadastroProdutos.

Also, you no need to mention the assembly there in, local: assembly=CadastroProdutos. So try to run the application after removing the above assembly code. Like as below,

local="clr-namespace:CadastroProdutos"